# Comparing the Hückel and extended Hückel methods

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry

I'm very confused about the differences between these methods. From my textbook, it states that the Hückel method only takes into account the π bonding interactions, while the extended Hückel method takes into account all the valence electrons. But what exactly does this do?

To my knowledge, the s, p<sub>*z*</sub>, p<sub>*x*</sub>, and p<sub>*y*</sub> orbitals are all orthogonal to one another and wouldn't mix anyways. Are shielding effects the only thing accounted for by extended Hückel theory?

Comment: Ever heard about sigma bonds? _That's_ the difference.

Comment: s, pz, px, and py on the same site are orthogonal. However, for example, an s on one site is not orthogonal to a px on a different site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the simple Hückel method (SHM) the basis set is limited to p orbitals. This set is limited in a great extent to p<sub>*z*</sub> orbitals which constraints the molecular plane to be the *xy* plane. Basically, you are limited to planar molecules.
  The inclusion of all valence s and p orbitals in the extended Hückel method (EHM) naturally lifts the spacial constraints and you can work with non-planar molecules.

These are the two first differences between the two methods. The other points are:

**SHM**:

- Orbital energies are limited to same-atom interactions, adjacent-atom interactions while all other interactions are 0.
- Fock matrix elements are not actually calculated.
- Overlap integrals are limited to 1 or 0.

**EHM**:

- Orbital energies are calculated and vary smoothly with geometry.
- Fock matrix elements are actually calculated.
- Overlap integrals are actually calculated.

You can look up the derivation and steps for the implementation of these two methods in this book that I used as a reference:

Errol G. Lewars; *Computational Chemistry, Introduction to the Theory and Applications of Molecular and Quantum Mechanics,* Second Edition;
Springer: 2011. DOI: [10.1007/978-90-481-3862-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-90-481-3862-3)

Comment: Would you be willing to comment on the Fock matrix elements? More specifically, I assume it's still $h + 2J - K$, but are there simple approximations for J and K?

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon that's where the empirical part of the method comes in. We obtain the whole matrix elements basically directly from experimental ionization potentials for their corresponding orbitals.

Answer (score 3):

Pentavalentcarbon brought up an interesting point that I thought I could elaborate on: How are the matrix elements of this simplified Hamiltonian obtained? I'll basically just summarize the relevant parts of this Chem-Libre section on the [Extended Hückel method](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al.)/10%3A_Theories_of_Electronic_Molecular_Structure/10.06%3A_Semi-Empirical_Methods%3A_Extended_H%C3%BCckel)

This is where the empirical part of this method comes into play. If you have the overlap matrix elements $S_{ij}$, then the elements of the Hamiltonian $H_{ij}$ can obtained using experimentally obtained values of a given orbital's ionization potential. The diagonal elements are simply taken to the negative of the ionization potential of the corresponding atomic orbital, $$H_{ii}=-\mathrm{IP}$$ The off-diagonal elements take only slightly more effort with $$H_{ij}=\frac{K}{2}(H_{ii}+H_{jj})S_{ij} \text{ , } i\not=j$$ $K$ is just a proportionality constant and a commonly used value is $1.75$, based on a study by Hoffman on the orbital energies of ethane.

Comment: Interesting. That expression is identical to what Q-Chem would call the Generalized Wolfsberg-Helmholtz guess, though its matrix elements are in the AO basis, and the diagonal elements are simply the diagonal from $T + V$. For other programs that can use EHM (Dalton comes to mind), I wonder what they are actually doing.